# Laravel: Ajax post request routing

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I am very new to laravel and laravel-5. When I do POST Request, I am getting 200 response with login request in firebug console.

**Routes.php**

```
Route::group
(
    [
        'prefix'    => '/',
        'namespace' => 'Landing'
    ],
    function()
    {
        Route::controller('',   'WelcomeController');
    }
);
```

**WelcomeController.php**

```
  public function postUserContact()
   { 
      print_r($_POST);
   }
```

**Ajax request:**

```
$.ajax({
  url           :   window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + '/user-contact',
  type      :   'POST',
  async     :   true,
  cache     :   false,
  processData   :   true,
  data      :   {name:name,email:email,message:message},
  success       :   function (returnedData)
  {console.log(returnedData)}
});
```

Please correct me if anything wrong

Comment: and your problem? ( **note:** 200 response means success)

Comment: @SHAZ. I am getting 200 response to login. But in my action is not login function.

Comment: Probably, you have an `auth` middleware in your WelcomeController constructor?!

Answer (score 0):

try it:

Routes.php

```
    Route::get('/', array('as' => 'index', 'uses' => 'WelcomeController@getIndex'));
    Route::post('/', array('as' => 'ajaxdata', 'uses' => 'WelcomeController@ajaxdata'));
```

WelcomeController.php

```
public function getIndex() { 
  return View::make('yourapp.index');
  // resources/views/yourapp/index.blade.php
}
public function ajaxdata() { 
  if (Request::ajax()) {
    $data = Input::all();
    //you access all data from ajax
  }
}
```

Ajax in your index.blade.php

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'ajaxdata',  //add url what you specify in routes.php
```

....